# Syncing but not closing a dbm

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, flush, dbm

Is it a problem to do :

```
import time
import dumbdbm

db = dumbdbm.open('db.db', 'c')

# modify the persistent dict / "DB" here
db['foo'] = 'bar'
db.sync()        

while True:
    # doing other things, sometimes modifying the db + syncing with .sync()
    time.sleep(1)
```

and to break the program with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> during the sleeping time, i.e. the `dumbdbm` **will not be properly closed** ?

Is [dumbdbm.sync()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dumbdbm.html#dumbdbm-objects) enough to guarantee safety of the datas, or is `.close()` absolutely mandatory?

Comment: You could close *before* you sleep.

Comment: @ScottHunter, it was a simplified code of my whole thing. I modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation implies](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dumbdbm.html#dumbdbm.dumbdbm.sync) syncing is enough when it says that calling that method synchronized the on-disk directory and data files.

However, I think the better approach here is to close the file before exiting. If you're always exiting with `Ctrl-C`, you can make this happen by registering a signal handler for `SIGINT` (which is the signal sent by `Ctrl-C`.) This signal handler should sync, close the DB, then call exit().

Comment: Thanks @gbe. Can you cite which part of the doc says it's enough?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a reference to that part of the documentation.